# Como comparar os valores que duas colunas no R e gerar uma coluna com o resultado da comparação

Tags: r

Tenho uma base com duas colunas:

```
Nota <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Nota_ei <- c(NA, 3, 1, NA, 7)
```

Preciso comparar as duas colunas para ver qual é maior, e criar um terceira coluna com maior resultado, usando R?

O que resultado seria:

```
Resultado <- c( 1, 3, 3, 4, 7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pmax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html), máximo *paralelo*.

```r
Nota <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Nota_ei <- c(NA, 3, 1, NA, 7)

pmax(Nota, Nota_ei, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 1 3 3 4 7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Se os vetores são vetores de uma base,

```r
base <- data.frame(
  Nota = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  Nota_ei = c(NA, 3, 1, NA, 7)
)
base$Resultado <- with(base, pmax(Nota, Nota_ei, na.rm = TRUE))
base
#>   Nota Nota_ei Resultado
#> 1    1      NA         1
#> 2    2       3         3
#> 3    3       1         3
#> 4    4      NA         4
#> 5    5       7         7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada Rui!!